# Telnet login and password failure from my command line

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, tcp, telnet

I am working on a node project, actually a tutorial on TCP Networking with the Net module. So, I am having issues connecting to telnet from my windows command line.

1. When I connect to telnet using the command line, I get this.

Welcome to Microsoft Telnet Client
Escape Character is 'CTRL+]'
Microsoft Telnet>

2. When I run this command- Microsoft Telnet> "o localhost", I get this
   connection to localhost...
   Welcome to Microsoft Telnet Service

login:

It prompts for login and password.

My challenge is how to get the username and the password to log in since it's my first time using telnet.

Please can someone help me to find a way to log in either by finding my password or resetting it, and creating a new one?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Launch your telnet client, and establish a connection to the telnet server. From a Windows computer with the built-in telnet client enabled, open a command prompt and type "telnet" followed by the other computer's IP address or name and press "Enter." Add the port address at the end of the command if required by the server.

Enter your account username and password at the login prompts. If you lost or forgot the password, you must sign in using another account with administrator rights.

Enter "passwd user_name" to reset the password of another account, replacing "user_name" with the account name. Enter a new password twice when prompted.

Enter "net user user_name new_password" if the other computer is running Windows, replacing "user_name" with the account username and "new_password" with a new password. If the account is part of a domain network, add the "/domain" switch at the end of the command. The password changes automatically without further prompting. You must have administrator privileges to change your own password on a Windows computer via telnet.

Aslo, Telnet is an very old and insecure technology instead use ssh which can provide better functionality and more security.